# What is the name of this geometrical function?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

In a two dimentional integer space, you have two points, A and B. This function returns an enumeration of the points in the quadrilateral subset bounded by A and B.

A = {1,1} B = {2,3}

Fn(A,B) = {{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3}}

I can implement it in a few lines of LINQ.

```
private void UnknownFunction(Point to, Point from, List<Point> list)
{
    var vectorX = Enumerable.Range(Math.Min(to.X, from.X), Math.Abs(to.X - from.Y) + 1);
    var vectorY = Enumerable.Range(Math.Min(to.Y, from.Y), Math.Abs(to.Y - from.Y) + 1);
    foreach (var x in vectorX)
        foreach (var y in vectorY)
            list.Add(new Point(x, y));
}
```

I'm fairly sure that this is a standard mathematical operation, but I can't think what it is.
Feel free to tell me that it's one line of code in your language of choice. Or to give me a cunning implementation with lambdas or some such.

But mostly I just want to know what it's *called*. It's driving me nuts.
It feels a little like a convolution, but it's been too long since I was at school for me to be sure.

Comment: Technically, this is a Diophantine problem.  However, because of the very restricted (ie, values always <=1 of each other) and orthogonal nature of this particular problem, it can be solved with the Cartesian product of input points.  Make it larger though, and you'll have to use a slightly more general solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the sets `{1,2}` and `{1,2,3}` in your specific example, or generally the Cartesian product of the `vectorX` and `vectorY` in your code example.

Comment: But it's specifically *not* the Cartesian product of `{1,1},{2,3}`, or is it?

Comment: Well, I suppose strictly speaking its the cartesian product of {VectorX->X ... VectorY->X} * {VectorX->Y ... VectorY->Y}, but that probably isn't what you're looking for

Comment: Well, I knew that at least part of it had a name. I'm not good with names.

Comment: If what you're talking about is the enumeration of integer lattice points in a polygon with integer lattice vertices, take a look at "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem" (you'll have to copy and paste the URL into your browser because it's not being correctly treated in this comment field).  Although Pick's theorem is well known, I don't think there's actually a term for the set of points in question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is a standard mathematical operation, if you wanted to describe it mathematically it would be described as such.

Given two points, (x_1,x_2) and (y_1,y_2) in N^2. Then take min_1 to be min(x_1,y_1) and max_1 to be max(x_1,y_1) and symetric operations for min_2 and max_2. Then the set is defined as:

Enum = { (a,b) :  a,b in N^2 and  min_1 <= a <= max_1 and min_2 <= b <= max_2 }

Which seems pretty arbitrary to me and I would say that it doesn't seem like a fairly standard mathematical operation to me.

Solving it using the Cartesian product becomes, trickier. It was simple to use the cartesian product when you have points that are so close together, but what about when you have {1,1} and {8,8}. Then the problem is a little more involved. You take the two sets:

{ a: min(x_1,y_1) <= a <= max(x_1,y_1) } and {b : min(x_2,y_2) <= b <= max(x_2,y_2) }

In both instances you're simply taking all the values in the range and enumerating across the space. Once again though, it feels like an arbitrary operation and maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think this has a well-known name. Besides enumerating the points in a rectangle.

Comment: I think it was the Cartesian product part of the question that made me think "This thing that I'm doing has a name". Possibly not the whole process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Integer / lattice points in bounds / rectangle.

(Similar to the name of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_points_in_convex_polyhedra)

Answer (score 1):

**Cartesian Product** using list comprehensions in

Python

```
[(x,y) for x in [1,2] for y in [1,2,3] ]
```

and Haskell

```
[(x,y) | x <- [1,2] , y <- [1,2,3] ]
```